# Date filter to compare 2 last full weeks on Tableau dashboard

Tags: date, tableau-api, dashboard, calculated-field

I need to compare data from periods of 2 weeks each time.
For example - week 10-17 OCT to week 17-24 OCT

I want to create a dashboard

When access the dashboard I want to choose each time a period of **LAST FULL 2 WEEKS** (Monday to Monday) regardless to today's date.

Tried to make a calculated filed that adds and reduces days according to current date with DATEPART. maybe there is a better way? because this did not work for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this, but for the sake of a quick answer that works...

Create a calculated field with this logic

`if (datepart('week',[Order Date])= (datepart('week',today())) -2)
    or (datepart('week',[Order Date])= (datepart('week',today())) -1)
    then 'Include'
    else 'Exclude' 
    end`

There are two things happening in this formula: first, we are retrieving the week number (1 through 52) from the date field ([order date]). Next we retrieve the week number for the current week and subtract 2 from the result. If the record ([Order Date]) is = to the current week minus 2, OR the current week minus 1, then "Include", otherwise exclude.

Then, you can add this field to the filter pane and set to only include 'Include'

Comment: This works great, another quick question, If I want to apply same thing but for a 10 week period. It takes only 22AUR-29AUG

Answer (score 2):

One issue you may want to consider with the above approach, if you have multiple years of data, you'll also need a year filter to keep to the current year, otherwise it will add previous years into your view. Alternatively, you can modify the filter calc as follows:

```
    IF  (DATEPART('year', [Date]) = DATEPART('year', today())
        AND DATEPART('week', [Date]) = (DATEPART('week', today()) -2)

    OR DATEPART('year', [Date]) = DATEPART('year', today()) 
        AND DATEPART('week', [Date]) = (DATEPART('week', today()) - 1))

        THEN 'Include'
        ELSE 'Exclude' 
        END
```